# Laravel populating the current class from its ID

Tags: php, laravel-4, load, eloquent

I'm looking build a solution in laravel 4 using Eloquent such as

```
$message_id = 123;
$message = New Message();
if(!$message->loadFromId($message_id)){
    return 'Failed to find message';
}else{
    return $message->get('Body');
}
```

However I cannot determine how to do this. I know laravel gas a 'find' method the returns the instance of the class but this is not what i need. I want to be able to load the current class and return a boolean. I understand laravel has a load method the requires a relation.

I assume I can create a new method such as 'loadFromId' with a series of laravel methods to simulate what I want. But I'm not sure. I guess I pull a 'relation' (whatever that is) from the database and use it with the load method.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Read the documentation, it's clear

Answer (score 0):

The find method is what you want:

```
$message_id = 123;
$message = Message::find($message_id);
if(!$message){
    return 'Failed to find message';
}else{
    return $message->Body;
}
```

Comment: I did not think of using it like this. Spose you could use if($message = Message::find($message_id)). I also have an internal error system that I use. Hence if I had a loadFromId method I would catch any exceptions and add the message to the error system. Retrieved by $message->getError('public') after false is returned. There are a few other reasons I wish to follow the above process.

Comment: You can still throw an Exception